# Is it possible to use `required: true` validation by clause?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose, mongoose-plugins

I have the following schema:

```
var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({});

Schema.add({
    type: {
       type: String
       , enum: ['one', 'two', 'three']
    }
});

Schema.add({
    title: {
       type: String
       //, required: true ned set by some conditional
    }
});
```

As you can from the preseding schema definition I have two field `type` and `title`. The second one (`title`) have to be `required: true` only if `type` is `(one | two)` and have to be `false` if type is `three`.

How could I do it with mongoose?

**EDIT:** thanks for the answers. I have one more related question that I ask here:

I it possible to remove field if that not required? Let's say the type if `three` but also been provided `title` field also. To prevent storing of unnecessary `title` in this case how to remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a function to the `required` validator in mongoose.

```
Schema.add({
  title: String,
  required: function(value) {
    return ['one', 'two'].indexOf(this.type) >= 0;
  }
});
```

The [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-required) doesn't explicity state that you can use a function as an argument but if you click `show code` you will see why this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the accepted answer using the [validate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-validate) option:

```
Schema.add({
  title: String,
  validate: [function(value) {
    // `this` is the mongoose document
    return ['one', 'two'].indexOf(this.type) >= 0;
  }, '{PATH} is required if type is either "one" or "two"']
});
```

UPDATE: I should have noted validators are only run if a field is not undefined with the only exception being required. So, this wouldn't be a good alternative.

Comment: Thanks. This is nice too,

Answer (score 0):

you could try one of the following:

```
Schema.add({
    title: {
       type: String
       //, required: true ned set by some conditional
    }
});

Schema.title.required = true;
```

or

```
var sky = 'gray'

var titleRequired = sky === 'blue' ? true : false

Schema.add({
    title: {
       type: String,
       required: titleRequired
    }
});
```

Comment: I need to get this case on creating new document: `new schemaModel({type: "one", "title": undefined})`;